# Conditions for a group of values

Tags: python, if-statement, conditional-statements

I'm trying to concatenate some conditions but it's getting quite hard to solve it, here's the problem:

I have a df with 3 columns:

```
| Column1 | Column2 | Column3 |
|:-------:|:-------:|:-------:|
| group1  | A       | x       |
| group1  | B       | p       |
| group1  | C       | y       |
| group2  | A       | x       |
| group2  | B       | j       |
| group2  | C       | y       |
| group3  | A       | x       |
| group3  | B       | p       |
| group3  | C       | z       |
| group4  | A       | h       |
| group4  | B       | p       |
| group4  | C       | y       |
```

So, what I'm trying to do is to check if for **each group** of values all the conditions are met. If one of them doesn't, all the group should be "KO".
Conditions:
-For groupx

- A = x or h
- B = p
- C = y

The output should be like this:

```
| Column1 | Column2 | Column3 | Column4 | Column5 |
|:-------:|:-------:|:-------:|:-------:|:-------:|
| group1  | A       | x       | OK      | OK      |
| group1  | B       | p       | OK      | OK      |
| group1  | C       | y       | OK      | OK      |
| group2  | A       | x       | OK      | KO      |
| group2  | B       | j       | KO      | KO      |
| group2  | C       | y       | OK      | KO      |
| group3  | A       | x       | OK      | KO      |
| group3  | B       | p       | OK      | KO      |
| group3  | C       | z       | KO      | KO      |
| group4  | A       | h       | OK      | OK      |
| group4  | B       | p       | OK      | OK      |
| group4  | C       | y       | OK      | OK      |
```

In column4 we have result for each row of the df and in column5 we check that or each group all the conditions are satisfied.

Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Actually my answer is pretty similar to that @Sachin Koli's, but we took a different approach for `Column5`

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Column1':['group1', 'group1','group1','group2','group2','group2','group3','group3','group3','group4','group4','group4'],
    'Column2':['A', 'B','C','A','B','C','A','B','C','A','B','C'],
    'Column3':['x', 'p','y','x','j','y','x','p','z','h','p','y']
    }, columns=['Column1', 'Column2', 'Column3', 'Column4', 'Column5'])

def helper(i, j):
    if (i=='A' and (j=='x' or j=='h')) or (i=='B' and j=='p') or (i=='C' and j=='y'):
        return 'OK'
    return 'KO'

df['Column4'] = df.apply(lambda x: helper(x[1], x[2]), axis=1)
    
for idx in df.index:    
    grp = df['Column1'].iloc[idx]
    df['Column5'].iloc[idx] = 'OK' if all(df[df['Column1']==grp]['Column4'] == 'OK') else 'KO'
```

UPDATE

You could use a list comprehension for Column5

```
df['Column5'] = ['OK' if all(df[df['Column1']==grp]['Column4'] == 'OK') else 'KO' for grp in df['Column1']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this... A simple function called in apply-lambda then for loop to get the desired results... Not sure this is the optimal way though...

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Column1":[1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4],
                   "Column2":["A","B","C","A","B","C","A","B","C","A","B","C"],
                   "Column3":["x","p","y","x","j","y","x","p","z","h","p","y"]})

# Sorting data on column1;
df = df.sort_values('Column1')
df.index = range(0,df.shape[0])

# Column4
def fun(x,y):
    if (x=='A' and y=='x') or (x=='A' and y=='h') or (x=='B' and y=='p') or (x=='C' and y=='y'):
        return "OK"
    else:
        return "KO"
df["Column4"] = df.apply(lambda x: fun(x["Column2"], x["Column3"]), axis=1)

# Column5
lst = []
for i in df["Column1"].unique():
    df_temp = df[df["Column1"] == i]
    if "KO" in list(df_temp["Column4"]):
        lst = lst + ["KO"]*df_temp.shape[0]
    else:
        lst = lst + ["OK"]*df_temp.shape[0]
df["Column5"] = lst
```

Hope this Helps...

```
# Output of df

    Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4 Column5
0         1       A       x      OK      OK
1         1       B       p      OK      OK
2         1       C       y      OK      OK
3         2       A       x      OK      KO
4         2       B       j      KO      KO
5         2       C       y      OK      KO
6         3       A       x      OK      KO
7         3       B       p      OK      KO
8         3       C       z      KO      KO
9         4       A       h      OK      OK
10        4       B       p      OK      OK
11        4       C       y      OK      OK
```

Comment: `Column5` requires `Column1` to be sorted for this answer to work.  For example, it would fail for `"Column1":[1,1,3,2,2,2,3,3,1,4,4,4]`

Comment: First of all thank you for the answer, but there is a problem. This question is simplefied, I mean, I have a df with more than 1 million rows and more than 200K groups and this loop takes a huge amount of time.

The first part is great beacause I have the info for each letter of column1, and like that I can compare if they are 'OK' or 'KO'. I was thinking on using something like a mask comparing the index of each group and then the column with 'KO' or 'OK' to generate athe new column5. But I'm not sure how to do it.

Thanks again!

Comment: I completely understand @EnriqueGE, probably what you can do is follow a part of code what bn_ln has posted here with a different approach... hope it might help you to get desired result much faster... Drop a like & accept the best answer that works for your problem statement... To grow & motivate community... Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

A solution without `for` loops:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"Column1":[1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4],
                   "Column2":["A","B","C","A","B","C","A","B","C","A","B","C"],
                   "Column3":["x","p","y","x","j","y","x","p","z","h","p","y"]})

def check(x, y):
    conditions = {"A": "x|h", "B": "p", "C": "y"}
    if y in conditions[x]:
        return "OK"
    else:
        return "KO"


df["Column4"] = df.apply(lambda row: check(row["Column2"], row["Column3"]), axis=1)
df["Column5"] = np.where(df.Column4.eq("OK").groupby(df.Column1).sum().eq(3).repeat(3), "OK", "KO")

print(df)
```

Out:

```
    Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4 Column5
0         1       A       x      OK      OK
1         1       B       p      OK      OK
2         1       C       y      OK      OK
3         2       A       x      OK      KO
4         2       B       j      KO      KO
5         2       C       y      OK      KO
6         3       A       x      OK      KO
7         3       B       p      OK      KO
8         3       C       z      KO      KO
9         4       A       h      OK      OK
10        4       B       p      OK      OK
11        4       C       y      OK      OK
```